# How to limit maximum number of items in category in yii?

Tags: php, validation, yii

I have page model. Pages are nested - each page can belong to another. Because of space limit I need to force maximum number of "main pages"(pages without parent page). The question is where is the best place to check that limit? In `beforeSave`? Or in custom validation rule? or elsewhere?

Comment: #yii irc is sugesting custom validator. I need to add that I'm not using ajax

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of custom rule for the class Page, provided that `parentId` attribute is the nullable foreign key to parent page, which sets to `null` if the Page has no parent, i.e. it is *Main Page*.

```
class Page extends CActiveRecord
{
    const MAINPAGES_LIMIT = 10;

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            ...
            array('parentId', 'mayNewMainPageBeCreated', 'on'=>'insert'),
            ...
        );
    }
    // custom rule validator
    public function mayNewMainPageBeCreated($attribute, $params)
    {
        $count = Page::model()->count("parentId IS NULL");
        if ($count >= self::MAINPAGES_LIMIT) {
            $this->addError($attribute, "Can't create more Main Pages");
        }
    }
}
```